# Expand and shorten file path of current cmd

Tags: windows-xp, cmd.exe

I'm unable to find anything regarding this on the net. E.g., When I'm in C:\PROGRA~1> I would like to expand it to C:\Program Files>. Also I would like to change other way around, when I'm in C:\Program Files> to short it to C:\PROGRA~1>. Note that I'm talking about cmd and when I'm in cmd and going through file and folders, not in batch file.

---

OK to end all confusion, this is what i want:

`C:\PROGRA~1> _`

`C:\PROGRA~1> <command>`

`C:\Program Files> _`

And other was around:

`C:\Program Files> _`

`C:\Program Files> <command>`

`C:\PROGRA~1> _`

I hope it's clear now xD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Expand and shorten file path of current cmd**
>
> When I'm in C:\PROGRA~1> I would like to expand it to C:\Program
>   Files>. Also I would like to change other way around, when I'm in
>   C:\Program Files> to short it to C:\PROGRA~1>. Note that I'm talking
>   about cmd and when I'm in cmd and going through file and folders, not
>   in batch file.

*I figured I'd just add this as an answer to expand on my comment and help ensure it's clearer what I was saying.*

### One Way

Since you're doing this from command prompt and NOT from a batch script, here are some suggestions.

1. Use the environmental variable to expand to the long path of the
   program files directory as such: `CD /D "%programfiles%"`
2. Once in the long path using the above environmental variable, type in or copy and paste this command to go to the short path of that same directory `FOR %A IN (.) DO CD "%~sA"`

Toggle between the two commands with the up arrow, etc. to change between the two since you're doing this from command line manually rather than a batch script.

---

### Another Way

You can just do a `DIR /D /X` command to get the short path names of the folders where that's applicable, and then do an explicit `CD /D "C:\ShortPathName~"` from CMD to go into that directory with the short path name.

In the other direction, you can do a `CD` command but before you press <kbd>**Enter**</kbd> just press <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> however many times you need to go through the folder names for the long path names that are auto-populated.

**NOTE:** *I'm not 100% certain with the* <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> *key on XP for auto-populating long path folder name, and I don't have anything XP wise to test it with right now, but those are some quick ideas I have for what you're explaining and some workarounds.*